# 100% Height Off-Canvas Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation and have a series of sections at height: 100%.

I'm using the off-canvas menu but it's only matching the height of the first section / the viewport. So once I scroll, the off-canvas menu is no longer aligned to the height of the viewport.

It's a similar issue to [Foundation 5 off-canvas full height of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158607/foundation-5-off-canvas-full-height-of-device).

I'm ending up with this:

[All good](https://i.imgur.com/GOxxWf9.png)

[After scrolling down to next section](https://i.imgur.com/257zzGR.png)

I think it can be solved by to adding position: fixed to left-off-canvas-menu, but that's not working.

It's driving me mad.

Answer (score 22):

The best option I can find so far is to add a couple of lines of css:

```
        .off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .off-canvas-wrap{  
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        }
```

Although this fixes it for the most part, scrolling on a touch device is not 100% perfect, every now and then you do get a weird scenario where the bottom of the browser drags upwards.

Comment: I've combined this answer with this article to create something that feels more natural on iOS devices http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/

Answer (score 3):

Here's the better answer:
it gives both 100% height and allows the center content to scroll.

```
.off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap, .main-section { height:100%; }
.main-section { overflow-y: auto; }
```

Comment: This is the only solution on the whole wide Internet which seems to work. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

put the below cords in your head.

```
  .off-canvas-wrap,.inner-wrap,.main-section{
      height:100%;   
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The codes attached above from my comment works something wrong.
Just put the below in your application.js

```
   $(function() {
         var timer;

         $(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
               $('.inner-wrap').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px" );
                }, 40);
          }).resize();
     });
```