# off-canvas navigation clipped on "short" page

Tags: css, navigation

This off-canvas navigation works OK except on the site splash page, which has very little content, and thus seems to create a vertical barrier. When the browser window narrows to the break point, and the user clicks the hamburger, the lowermost *li* item in the navigation is clipped. I have tinkered with overflow and z-index with no luck. (most of this based on a David Bushell article)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer-wrap">
<div id="inner-wrap">
    <header id="top" role="banner">
        <div class="block">
            <h1 class="block-title">another title here</h1>
            <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open-btn" href="#nav">-Nav-</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="block">
            <ul><!--
             --><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="bj-cole.php">Music</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="john-greenway.php">Authors</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="manhood.php">Ideas</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="eugene-atget.php">Design</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="eclecticism.php">Other</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="mail02.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="close-btn" id="nav-close-btn" href="#top">Return to Content</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="main" role="main">
        <article class="block prose">
        <h1>Verbiage verbiage verbiage</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. </p>
<p>&mdash; Author Goeshere</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <!--<footer role="contentinfo">
        <div class="block prose">
        </div>
    </footer>-->
</div>
<!--/#inner-wrap-->
</div>
<!--/#outer-wrap-->
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;}
@viewport {
  width: device-width;}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,summary {
  display: block;}

audio,canvas,video {
  display: inline-block;}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

a:active,a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

#top h1.block-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family:Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", Georgia, serif;
  letter-spacing:.2em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

ul, ol {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  color: #47290C;
  position: relative;/* was   */
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 20em;
  background: #996600;
}

.highlight {
  background: #fff699;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.prose ul, .prose ol {
  list-style: outside disc;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.prose p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.prose p.small {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 0.8125em;
  line-height: 1.84615em;
  margin-bottom: 1.84615em;
}
.prose p.medium {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1.71429em;
  margin-bottom: 1.71429em;
}
.prose p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.prose h1 {
  font-size: 1.875em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.prose h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.prose a {
  color: #6d7173;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1cfe5;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.prose a:focus, .prose a:hover {
  color: #4ab336;
  border-bottom-color: #77b36b;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5em 1.25em;
  max-width: 60em;
}

.close-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 2.625em;
  height: 2.25em;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: #47290C url("../img/close-btn.svg") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.875em 1.875em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.no-svg .close-btn {
  background-image: url("../img/close-btn.png");
}
.close-btn:focus, .close-btn:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 2.625em;
  height: 2.25em;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: #996600 url("../img/nav-icon.svg") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.875em 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.no-svg .nav-btn {
  background-image: url("../img/nav-icon.png");
}
.nav-btn:hover, .nav-btn:focus {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

#outer-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav {
  border: 0;
  z-index: 200;/*was tested at 900*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav .close-btn {
  display: none;
}
#nav .block-title {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
#nav .block {
  z-index: 200;/*was not here at all*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75em 1.25em;
  background: #47290C;
  /* following is test */
    border-top-color:#92CFED;
    border-top-width:3px;
    border-top-style:solid;
}
#nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
  display: block;
}
#nav ul:before, #nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#nav li {
  display: block;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fee;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1.28571em;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
}
#nav li a:focus, #nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#nav li.is-active a {
  color: #fff;
}

#top {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background: #996600;
}
#top .block-title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.875em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#top .nav-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.2em;
  left: 1.875em;
}

#main {
  /*background: #F5F2EC;*/
  background:#FCF4E0;
}
#main .block {
  padding: 2.625em 1.875em;
}

footer[role="contentinfo"] {
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 45.0625em) {
  #top .nav-btn {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }

  #nav .close-btn {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  #nav .block-title {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  #nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #nav li a {
    padding: 0.42857em 0.85714em;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
  #nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 5.25em;
  }
  #nav:not(:target) {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0;
  }
  #nav:target .close-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  #nav .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5.0em;
    left: 1.875em;
  }
  #nav .block {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #nav li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #nav li.is-active:after {
    z-index: 50;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -0.03125em;
    margin-top: -0.625em;
    border-top: 0.625em transparent solid;
    border-bottom: 0.625em transparent solid;
    border-right: 0.625em white solid;
  }
  #nav li a {
    padding: 0.85714em 2.14286em;
  }

  .js-ready #nav {
    height: 100%;
    /*following new z-index*/
    z-index:500;
    width: 70%;
    background: #47290C;/* was 333333*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    overflow:visible;
  }
  .js-ready #nav .block {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .js-ready #nav .close-btn {
    display: block;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  .js-ready #nav .close-btn:focus, .js-ready #nav .close-btn:hover {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .js-ready #nav {
    left: -70%;
  }
  .js-ready #inner-wrap {
    left: 0;
  }

  .js-nav #inner-wrap {
    left: 70%;
  }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function(window, document, undefined)
{

    // helper functions

    var trim = function(str)
    {
        return str.trim ? str.trim() : str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    };

    var hasClass = function(el, cn)
    {
        return (' ' + el.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cn + ' ') !== -1;
    };

    var addClass = function(el, cn)
    {
        if (!hasClass(el, cn)) {
            el.className = (el.className === '') ? cn : el.className + ' ' + cn;
        }
    };

    var removeClass = function(el, cn)
    {
        el.className = trim((' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' ' + cn + ' ', ' '));
    };

    var hasParent = function(el, id)
    {
        if (el) {
            do {
                if (el.id === id) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (el.nodeType === 9) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while((el = el.parentNode));
        }
        return false;
    };

    // normalize vendor prefixes

    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var transform_prop = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
        transition_prop = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transition'),
        transition_end = (function() {
            var props = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
                'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition'       : 'transitionend'
            };
            return props.hasOwnProperty(transition_prop) ? props[transition_prop] : false;
        })();

    window.App = (function()
    {
        var _init = false, app = { };
        var inner = document.getElementById('inner-wrap'),
            nav_open = false,
            nav_class = 'js-nav';

        app.init = function()
        {
            if (_init) {
                return;
            }
            _init = true;

            var closeNavEnd = function(e)
            {
                if (e && e.target === inner) {
                    document.removeEventListener(transition_end, closeNavEnd, false);
                }
                nav_open = false;
            };

            app.closeNav =function()
            {
                if (nav_open) {
                    // close navigation after transition or immediately
                    var duration = (transition_end && transition_prop) ? parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(inner, '')[transition_prop + 'Duration']) : 0;
                    if (duration > 0) {
                        document.addEventListener(transition_end, closeNavEnd, false);
                    } else {
                        closeNavEnd(null);
                    }
                }
                removeClass(doc, nav_class);
            };

            app.openNav = function()
            {
                if (nav_open) {
                    return;
                }
                addClass(doc, nav_class);
                nav_open = true;
            };

            app.toggleNav = function(e)
            {
                if (nav_open && hasClass(doc, nav_class)) {
                    app.closeNav();
                } else {
                    app.openNav();
                }
                if (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            };

            // open nav with main "nav" button
            document.getElementById('nav-open-btn').addEventListener('click', app.toggleNav, false);

            // close nav with main "close" button
            document.getElementById('nav-close-btn').addEventListener('click', app.toggleNav, false);

            // close nav by touching the partial off-screen content
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e)
            {
                if (nav_open && !hasParent(e.target, 'nav')) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    app.closeNav();
                }
            },
            true);

            addClass(doc, 'js-ready');

        };

        return app;

    })();

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', window.App.init, false);
    }

})(window, window.document);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in multiple places..

First your a button was after the ul with the nav and the nav itself had a negative top value that pushed it way too far down.
The revised code in the pen should do the job

```js
(function(window, document, undefined)
{

    // helper functions

    var trim = function(str)
    {
        return str.trim ? str.trim() : str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    };

    var hasClass = function(el, cn)
    {
        return (' ' + el.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cn + ' ') !== -1;
    };

    var addClass = function(el, cn)
    {
        if (!hasClass(el, cn)) {
            el.className = (el.className === '') ? cn : el.className + ' ' + cn;
        }
    };

    var removeClass = function(el, cn)
    {
        el.className = trim((' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' ' + cn + ' ', ' '));
    };

    var hasParent = function(el, id)
    {
        if (el) {
            do {
                if (el.id === id) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (el.nodeType === 9) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while((el = el.parentNode));
        }
        return false;
    };

    // normalize vendor prefixes

    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var transform_prop = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
        transition_prop = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transition'),
        transition_end = (function() {
            var props = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
                'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition'       : 'transitionend'
            };
            return props.hasOwnProperty(transition_prop) ? props[transition_prop] : false;
        })();

    window.App = (function()
    {
        var _init = false, app = { };
        var inner = document.getElementById('inner-wrap'),
            nav_open = false,
            nav_class = 'js-nav';

        app.init = function()
        {
            if (_init) {
                return;
            }
            _init = true;

            var closeNavEnd = function(e)
            {
                if (e && e.target === inner) {
                    document.removeEventListener(transition_end, closeNavEnd, false);
                }
                nav_open = false;
            };

            app.closeNav =function()
            {
                if (nav_open) {
                    // close navigation after transition or immediately
                    var duration = (transition_end && transition_prop) ? parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(inner, '')[transition_prop + 'Duration']) : 0;
                    if (duration > 0) {
                        document.addEventListener(transition_end, closeNavEnd, false);
                    } else {
                        closeNavEnd(null);
                    }
                }
                removeClass(doc, nav_class);
            };

            app.openNav = function()
            {
                if (nav_open) {
                    return;
                }
                addClass(doc, nav_class);
                nav_open = true;
            };

            app.toggleNav = function(e)
            {
                if (nav_open && hasClass(doc, nav_class)) {
                    app.closeNav();
                } else {
                    app.openNav();
                }
                if (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            };

            // open nav with main "nav" button
            document.getElementById('nav-open-btn').addEventListener('click', app.toggleNav, false);

            // close nav with main "close" button
            document.getElementById('nav-close-btn').addEventListener('click', app.toggleNav, false);

            // close nav by touching the partial off-screen content
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e)
            {
                if (nav_open && !hasParent(e.target, 'nav')) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    app.closeNav();
                }
            },
            true);

            addClass(doc, 'js-ready');

        };

        return app;

    })();

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', window.App.init, false);
    }

})(window, window.document);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;}
@viewport {
  width: device-width;}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,summary {
  display: block;}

audio,canvas,video {
  display: inline-block;}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

a:active,a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

#top h1.block-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family:Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", Georgia, serif;
  letter-spacing:.2em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

ul, ol {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  color: #47290C;
  position: relative;/* was   */
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 20em;
  background: #996600;
}

.highlight {
  background: #fff699;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.prose ul, .prose ol {
  list-style: outside disc;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.prose p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.prose p.small {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 0.8125em;
  line-height: 1.84615em;
  margin-bottom: 1.84615em;
}
.prose p.medium {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1.71429em;
  margin-bottom: 1.71429em;
}
.prose p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.prose h1 {
  font-size: 1.875em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.prose h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.prose a {
  color: #6d7173;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1cfe5;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.prose a:focus, .prose a:hover {
  color: #4ab336;
  border-bottom-color: #77b36b;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5em 1.25em;
  max-width: 60em;
}

.close-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 2.625em;
  height: 2.25em;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: #47290C url("../img/close-btn.svg") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.875em 1.875em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.no-svg .close-btn {
  background-image: url("../img/close-btn.png");
}
.close-btn:focus, .close-btn:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 2.625em;
  height: 2.25em;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: #996600 url("../img/nav-icon.svg") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.875em 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.no-svg .nav-btn {
  background-image: url("../img/nav-icon.png");
}
.nav-btn:hover, .nav-btn:focus {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

#outer-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav {
  border: 0;
  z-index: 200;/*was tested at 900*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav .close-btn {
  display: none;
}
#nav .block-title {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
#nav .block {
  z-index: 200;/*was not here at all*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75em 1.25em;
  background: #47290C;
  /* following is test */
    border-top-color:#92CFED;
    border-top-width:3px;
    border-top-style:solid;
}
#nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
  display: block;
}
#nav ul:before, #nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#nav li {
  display: block;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fee;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1.28571em;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
}
#nav li a:focus, #nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#nav li.is-active a {
  color: #fff;
}

#top {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background: #996600;
}
#top .block-title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.875em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#top .nav-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.2em;
  left: 1.875em;
}

#main {
  /*background: #F5F2EC;*/
  background:#FCF4E0;
}
#main .block {
  padding: 2.625em 1.875em;
}

footer[role="contentinfo"] {
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 45.0625em) {
  #top .nav-btn {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }

  #nav .close-btn {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  #nav .block-title {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  #nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #nav li a {
    padding: 0.42857em 0.85714em;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
  #nav {

    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5em;

  }
  #nav:not(:target) {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0;
  }
  #nav:target .close-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  #nav .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5.0em;
    left: 1.875em;
  }
  #nav .block {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #nav li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #nav li.is-active:after {
    z-index: 50;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -0.03125em;
    margin-top: -0.625em;
    border-top: 0.625em transparent solid;
    border-bottom: 0.625em transparent solid;
    border-right: 0.625em white solid;
  }
  #nav li a {
    padding: 0.85714em 2.14286em;
  }

  .js-ready #nav {
    height: 100%;
    /*following new z-index*/
    z-index:500;
    width: 70%;
    background: #47290C;/* was 333333*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    overflow:visible;
  }
  .js-ready #nav .block {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .js-ready #nav .close-btn {
    display: block;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  .js-ready #nav .close-btn:focus, .js-ready #nav .close-btn:hover {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .js-ready #nav {
    left: -70%;
  }
  .js-ready #inner-wrap {
    left: 0;
  }

  .js-nav #inner-wrap {
    left: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-wrap">
<div id="inner-wrap">
    <header id="top" role="banner">
        <div class="block">
            <h1 class="block-title">another title here</h1>
            <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open-btn" href="#nav">-Nav-</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="block">
          <a class="close-btn" id="nav-close-btn" href="#top">Return to Content</a>
            <ul><!--
             --><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="bj-cole.php">Music</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="john-greenway.php">Authors</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="manhood.php">Ideas</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="eugene-atget.php">Design</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="eclecticism.php">Other</a></li><!--
             --><li><a href="mail02.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="main" role="main">
        <article class="block prose">
        <h1>Verbiage verbiage verbiage</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. Lorem ipsum dolor and a whole lot more will go here. </p>
<p>&mdash; Author Goeshere</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <!--<footer role="contentinfo">
        <div class="block prose">
        </div>
    </footer>-->
</div>
<!--/#inner-wrap-->
</div>
<!--/#outer-wrap-->
```

Comment: funkysoulzh your suggestion is 95 percent effective. When I test that, the "close" button is missing, and I don't have a way to send the navigation back to its hidden origin. I will tinker and see if I can restore it.

Comment: it's not perfect yet.. but this should show you how it works.. moved to codepen: http://codepen.io/funkysoul/pen/QdjzZR

Comment: this has been discussed in greater depth at ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158607/foundation-5-off-canvas-full-height-of-device)